# How to get rid of -0 in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am writing a program in which there are some operations being performed on a floating point number. After I debugged the program, I came to know that for a particular test case, the value of the `variable equals -2.38418579e-07`. Now I have cout precision set to 2 digits after decimal. So when I print it, it prints it as -0.00.

However, I would like the output to be 0.00 instead of -0.00. I have tried various `if` conditions on the variable's value. However, they do not help. Can anyone suggest how to get rid of -0.00 in C++

Comment: `std::signbit` should help.

Comment: Why not just round it?

Comment: What about checking the output: `if(output == "-0.00") output = "0.00";` (assuming output is a std::string)

Comment: Is the value important or does it reprensent 0? Can you do `if(fabs(variable) < epsilon) variable = 0.0`?

Comment: Also, floating-point comparisons (under ieee) ignores sign when comparing for zero, so -0.00 == 0.00. As said, you can round it, check for zero and abs if needed.

Comment: E.g., to [round `x` to 2 decimal digits, `std::round(100*x)/100`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I thought that would be the solution too, but when I tried it it still prints "-0.00".

Comment: @Shaggi: Floating point comparisons would use the actual value (`-2.3E-7`), not the rounded -0.0

Comment: @DieterLücking's suggestion is the best approach, because it's a purely cosmetic concern, and it's the best way to ensure that all cases are handled.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, of course :) I just pointed out that when comparing zeros, sign is not considered.

Comment: you can only do that equals comparison in ascii/strings.  never do an equals comparison with a floating point number.

Comment: that obviously doesn't answer your question, but are you *sure* you actually want to do that? -0.00 can tell that the original number was negative, which i think can be quite useful in most scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should define a tolerance number as threshold, where the absolute value of any floating point number bellow this threshold would be considered as zero. For example you could define this threshold as:

```
#define zero 1e-6
```

Then you could use the following construct to "filter" your floating point numbers:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T> sanitize(T &&num) {
  return std::abs(num) < zero? T{} : num;    
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f27958a287ecd45f)

Notice that I use SFINAE in order for the `sanitize` function to accepts as input only floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the output to be 0.00 instead of -0.00

I like the other answers better.  But in a crunch you can always use brute force ... (are you sure you can ignore the actual results?)

```
std::string rslt;
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << variable;  // use same formatting as in your example

   size_t minusSignIndx = ss.str().find("-0.00");

   if (minusSignIndx != std::string::npos)
      rslt = " 0.00"; // found the nasty, ignore it
   else
      rslt = ss.str(); // not nasty, use it
}
//... use rslt
```

Comment: can you explain why you used `find` instead of `if (ss.str() == "-0.00")`

Comment: @M.M - no.  Minimal thought was involved.  Comparison has  the advantage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every floating point in a certain interval [ low , -0.0] will be printed "-0.00".

Thus you have to find low:

- such that print(predecessor(low)) => "-0.01"
- such that print(low) => "-0.00"

Then, you'll be able to write something like (nan apart...)

```
double filter(double x) {
    double low = ... ;
    return (x < low)
        ? x
        : ((x > 0.0)
            ? x
            : 0.0) ;
}
```

If you have a correctly rounded printf, and manage your arithmetic to be strictly IEEE754 conformant with appropriate compiler flags, the exact value of low is the nearest double to -1/200, greater than -1/200 (I write 1/200 rather than -0.005 because I'm speaking of the decimal value, not the double)

What we have with correctly rounded sscanf("-0.005","%lf",d): the double result is smaller than -1/200. I did check that with exact arithmetic like for example found in Pharo Smalltalk language:

```
[-0.005 < (-1/200) and: [-0.005 successor > (-1/200)]] assert.
```

Its successor is greater than -1/200 (necessarily, above check is just foolproofing).

Thus you can write (notice the <= low):

```
double filter(double x) {
    double low = 0.005 ;
    return (x <= low)
        ? x
        : ((x > 0.0)
            ? x
            : 0.0) ;
}
```